# MYSQL ERROR 1452 A foriegn key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a registration form that is working perfectly, but for some reason it wasn't adding to the database. SO I tested this query in phpmyadmin and I found this error

The query:

```
INSERT INTO `EMTS`(`name`, `nickname`, `age`, `number`, `city`, `password`, `street`, `building`) 
VALUES ("Alice","Aa","21","414514151","New York","111","main","x")
```

I didn't fill the other columns on purpose. In other database this wouldn't cause any problem

The error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`emts`, CONSTRAINT `fk_EMTS_shifts1` FOREIGN KEY (`shifts_idshifts`) REFERENCES `shifts` (`idshifts`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

This is the emts table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.EMTS(
idEMTS INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
nickname VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
age VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
number VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
shifts_idshifts INT(45) NOT NULL,
bloodtype_id INT NOT NULL,
street VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
building VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idEMTS),
  INDEX fk_EMTS_shifts1_idx(shifts_idshifts ASC),
  INDEX fk_EMTS_bloodtype1_idx(bloodtype_id ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX nickname_UNIQUE(nickname ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_EMTS_shifts1
    FOREIGN KEY (shifts_idshifts)
    REFERENCES mydb.shifts(idshifts)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_EMTS_bloodtype1
    FOREIGN KEY (bloodtype_id)
    REFERENCES mydb.bloodtype(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is bloodtype table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.bloodtype(
type INT NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is shifts table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.shifts(
startdate INT NOT NULL,
enddate VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
day VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
idshifts INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (idshifts))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I don't get what's wrong?

Comment: You answer is right there, it needs `shifts_idshifts` filled in and you didn't fill it in.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your query on my local MySQL instance.

As you noted, you did not provide values for your foreign key columns. But they are NOT NULL columns, and they have no default. So MySQL fills in the value 0.

I demonstrate this by dropping the FOREIGN KEY constraints and trying the INSERT again:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `EMTS`(`name`, `nickname`, `age`, `number`, `city`, `password`, `street`, `building`) 
    -> VALUES ("Alice","Aa","21","414514151","New York","111","main","x");
Query OK, 1 row affected, 3 warnings (0.02 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'email' doesn't have a default value           |
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'shifts_idshifts' doesn't have a default value |
| Warning | 1364 | Field 'bloodtype_id' doesn't have a default value    |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from EMTS;
+--------+-------+----------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
| idEMTS | name  | nickname | age | number    | email | city     | password | shifts_idshifts | bloodtype_id | street | building |
+--------+-------+----------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
|      3 | Alice | Aa       | 21  | 414514151 |       | New York | 111      |               0 |            0 | main   | x        |
+--------+-------+----------+-----+-----------+-------+----------+----------+-----------------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

Notice both of the foreign key columns are given the value 0.

If you don't want to provide values for the foreign key columns, make them nullable columns. It's okay for a NULL to exist, it won't cause a foreign key constraint violation. Whereas 0 is a non-NULL value, but it doesn't exist in the referenced tables for shifts and bloodtypes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html says:

> For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT
>   clause, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for the
>   column, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles
>   the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional
>     tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables,
>     an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row
>     of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows will have been
>     inserted.
> - If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit
>     default value for the column data type.

The implicit default value for an integer column is 0.

This is a strange behavior for MySQL that has caused many developers to be confused. If the column is NOT NULL, then why does it allow us to insert NULL, and default to some unspecified implicit default? It's counter-intuitive.

For this reason, strict mode has been made the default in newer versions of MySQL 5.7 and later. You can also set strict mode yourself:

```
mysql> SET sql_mode='strict_all_tables';

mysql> INSERT INTO `EMTS`(`name`, `nickname`, `age`, `number`, `city`, `password`, `street`, `building`) 
    -> VALUES ("Alice","Aa","21","414514151","New York","111","main","x");
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'email' doesn't have a default value
```

Comment: But can I update the null objects later on ? FOr instance, when I want to fill the table bloodtype , I am going to insert into the bloodtype_id foreign key the value of bloodtype table primary key(id)  .Sorry I'm new to sql

Comment: Yes, you can insert NULL for columns that allow NULL (but not if the column is declared `NOT NULL`, as yours are). Then you can use `UPDATE` later to give the row a value that satisfies the foreign key.